# "Autodesk is not defined" when running Forge viewer in Fusion 360 palette

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm working for a project where we need to run Forge viewer in palette of Autodesk Fusion 360.
I created a sample which runs successfully when tried in browser. There I could see Forge viewer as expected. But when I try same in Fusion 360 palette, I get error as "Autodesk is not defined".
Here in sample, try by changing URN and access token: https://rahulkhandepts.github.io/
Can someone please help? Thank you.[image]

I tried different samples by running in Fusion 360 palette. But no success.

Comment: I would take a look at line 70 of the Index and 170 and see whats going on there.  Might be a simple typo perhaps.

Comment: yes but it works perfectly fine in browser but not in palette of Fusion 360.

Comment: I just noticed something .. the actual error is Unexpected Token of = .. so 
Look at line 170 and look for the = and start working out what could be happening.  It might work one way but not another, then think about what is the difference and follow that.

Comment: Following up on my answer, if your code works fine in browser but not in a Fusion 360 palette, check for any permission or CORS limitations there. Perhaps Fusion doesn't allow external JS scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The `Autodesk` namespace is added to the global scope after you load the Viewer JavaScript library into your page, for example, using:

```html
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js"></script>
```

Make sure that your custom JavaScript code (the `initPage` function that's throwing the exception) is executed *after* the viewer library is loaded.